# How To Make Custom Alert Dialog Display Correctly

Tags: java, android, checkbox, dialog, popup

Having Troubles making this customer dialog box look correctly.

Here is my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<!--               android:padding="8dp" -->

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />

<ScrollView 
  android:paddingTop="2.0dip" 
  android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="4dp"      
    android:padding="5.0dip" />

   </ScrollView>

   <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:text="Do Not Show Me This Again"
     android:textColor="#FFF" >
    </CheckBox>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68717396/sddsds.png
sorry about the crappy line, but where the line is, this is where the scroll view ends, i want it to fill as much text as it can, and keep the checkbox a little height, (Not Cropped or anything) Just utilize all the space.

Comment: if you look to the "api demos" collection of samples from Google, the one that you can also download with SDK manager, there is some good example about how to do this and how to customize this kind of part of your UI. Considering the api demos itself the most interesting section in your case is the "App" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<!--               android:padding="8dp" -->

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       />

<ScrollView 
    android:paddingTop="2.0dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/checkBox1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="10dp"         
    android:padding="5.0dip" />

</ScrollView>

<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"     
     android:text="Do Not Show Me This Again"
     android:textColor="#FFF" >
</CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know if this is the result you are looking for.

Comment: "Yeah still looks the same for the layout, the scroll view is only showing just inside the top line and the line i drew in the image above. thats all.